# Dynamically styling JSON list input

Tags: json, list, jquery-mobile

my first question here after reading and attempting many responses... and I should confess that I'm pretty new to all this.

I have a long list stored in JSON format. It's well over 500 items long. I would like this to be styled using `data-role="listview"` on the `<ul>`.

The first renders the whole list but fails to style it:

```
<div id="ListDiv"></div>
<script>
    $.getJSON('BookList.json', function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.BookList) {
            output+="<li>" + data.BookList[i].UniqueIndex + ": " + data.BookList[i].Title + " | " + data.BookList[i].published +"</li>";
        };
        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("ListDiv").innerHTML=output;
        $("#ListDiv ul").append(' id="List" data-role="listview" ');
        $('#List').listview('refresh');
  });
</script>
```

the second renders only the last item but styles it:

```
<div>
<ul id="List" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
<script>
    $.getJSON('BookList.json', function(data) {
        var output=""; 
        for (var i in data.BookList) {
        output="<li>" + data.BookList[i].UniqueIndex + ": " + data.BookList[i].Title + " | " + data.BookList[i].published +"</li>";
        };
        document.getElementById("List").innerHTML=output;
       $('#List').listview('refresh');
  });
</script>
```

I've been trying to understand why these scripts function differently and what I have to do to get the entire list formatted correctly. I'm sure that my inexperience using jQuery Mobile is to blame.

Thanks

Comment: $("#ListDiv ul").append(' id="List" data-role="listview" '); The id and data-role are both attributes of the unordered list. So you could either set     output='<ul id="List data-role="listview">' at the beginning or add the attributes using $("#List").attr() later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example the methods are wrong. I mean the script does not do what you want.

This

```
document.getElementById("ListDiv").innerHTML=output;
$("#ListDiv ul").append(' id="List" data-role="listview" ');
```

Should be like this

```
$("#ListDiv").append('<ul id="List" data-role="listview"></ul>');
```

You don't need this

```
document.getElementById("ListDiv").innerHTML=output;
```

And since you are using jquery, the equivalent is

```
$("ListDiv").innerHTML=output;
```

But you don't need this.

Your complete first example should be

```
<div id="ListDiv"></div>
<script>
    $.getJSON('BookList.json', function(data) {
        var output="";
        for (var i in data.BookList) {
            output+="<li>" + data.BookList[i].UniqueIndex + ": " + data.BookList[i].Title + " | " + data.BookList[i].published +"</li>";
        }
        $("#ListDiv").append('<ul id="List" data-role="listview"></ul>');
        $('#List').append(output);
        $('#List').listview();   //<-- here
  });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my code because I have forgotten I very important thing.
When your ul tag is static (html declaration) and you just add elements to it then in the end you call `$('#List').listview('refresh');`
but when you create your list dynamically (you populate the ul tag with javascript) then you use `$('#List').listview();` 
This should work.

[A demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bujar/WYYkc/)

Comment: Thanks Alkis. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain and correct my code. I tried your rewrite of the first example. It resulted in an unformatted list. I also tried Aaron's example below and it didn't work. Unfortunately I don't have time now to play with more combinations of code but I will get back to you.

Comment: Bingo! It now works. I appreciate you not only providing a solution but explaining it too.

Comment: ah... I've noticed that this generates two copies of the JSON output. The first is styled correctly. The second copy appears below it and is unstyled. I can't figure out why it should be producing two sets.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Are you sure you haven't forgotten something in your js that produces duplicates? The above code works correctly as you can see in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('BookList.json', function(data) {
  var output='<ul id="List" data-role="listview">';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        output+="<li>" + BookList.UniqueIndex + ": " + BookList.Title + " | " + BookList.published +"</li>";
    };
    output+="</ul>";
    $("#ListDiv").append(output);
    $('#List').listview();
});
```

This code should work.
As I mentioned in my comment, the data-role and id are properties so you need to specify them within the  or add them using $("#List").attr()

Also when you add in a listview completely dynamically you must initialize it by calling .listview() before you call any other listview methods. If your listview was already declared in HTML and you were just updating it, then you would just call listview("refresh").

Here's the fiddle I was playing with:
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HQLdd/1/)

Quick edit: I think your second code section would actually work if you were just using

```
output += "<li>" + data.BookList[i].UniqueIndex + ": " + data.BookList[i].Title + " | " + data.BookList[i].published +"</li>";
```

instead of "output=" (And the .listview() replacement we talked of earlier). The "+=" makes sure that you are appending the string to the end of what's already there, the "=" just replaces the string with a new one each time.

I didn't run this code though since the above example is working.

Also, Alkis has some good explanations for some of the changes I made also. So make sure to check his/her answer out!

Comment: Aaron. This is a really good explanation and helps me clearly see why my code wouldn't work. I tried your code rewrite and I ended up with a blank page i.e. none of the list showed up at all. I also tried to edit that one line into my second code section and, again, ended up with a blank page. As I said above in reply to Alkis, I'm afraid I don't have time right now to continue to figure this out but I will get back to it tomorrow I hope. I just wanted to give you feedback and thank you.